# Where does pulseaudio store volume information for individual ports?

Tags: port, volume, pulseaudio

I'm working on a custom implementation of pulseaudio in C and I'm trying to set the volume for different output ports (i.e. external speaker, headphones, etc). The problem is, pulse only has a method for setting the volume for the entire sink, even though pulse itself is aware of multiple ports and somehow stores different volumes for each. Does anyone know where these are actually stored? I tried fishing around in the source but was not able to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

After contacting the developers, it appears there is no way to do this at the moment.